# Update existing excel sheet with openxml and C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I need to export a large amount of data from database to excel. I have created a method to export data from a select..but I managed to create a new excel. Not to update an existing one. I've searched on the internet but I cannot understand what am I doing wrong.

Here is my code for the method:

```
public static void ExportDSToExcel(DataSet ds, string destination)
    {
        using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(destination, true))
        {
            //var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
            workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

            uint sheetId = 1;

            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
                sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
                string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

                if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    sheetId =
                        sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                }

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                    foreach (String col in columns)
                    {
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }
            }
```

And here is where I call the method:

```
string _oracleConnection = "Data Source=XXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXXX;Password=YYYYY";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(_oracleConnection);
        using (con = new OracleConnection(_oracleConnection))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT connect_by_root proj_catg_name, parent_proj_catg_id,LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (proj_catg_short_name, '-'),'-') id_path, proj_catg_name FROM pcatval start with  proj_catg_name in ('XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX') CONNECT BY PRIOR proj_catg_id = parent_proj_catg_id ";

                con.Open();
                DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                oda.Fill(ds);
                string destination = @"D:\TEST.xlsx";
                P_IAP.Excelfile.ExportDSToExcel(ds, destination);
            }

            Excelfile excelfile = new Excelfile();
```

Do you have any idea what should I change? Lets say that I wanna update an excel file named TEST and the sheet called Sheet1

Comment: Please help me understand what am I doing wrong..

Comment: can you please post you correct and complete code in order to check the wrong part ?

Comment: I added my code..and the one where I call the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify a Excel file by OpenXml and save it again you should open it using it's **stream** :

```
byte[] ByteArrayContent = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.Write(ByteArrayContent , 0, (int)ByteArrayContent .Length);
    using (SpreadsheetDocument workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(mStream , true))
    {
       uint sheetId = 1;

        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
            sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
            string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

            if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
            {
                sheetId =
                    sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
            }

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

            List<String> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                foreach (String col in columns)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(SaveAsPath, mStream.ToArray()); 
}
```

it also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203150/openxml-spreadsheat-save-as)

Comment: It's not working. I mean..I copy your example and put my code inside the breaks..and nothing happens

Comment: if the new file is generated then the problem is, you should save the changes that is done by OpenXml. i suppose your `sheet` or `newRow` should have a method named `save()` . before saving using stream you should call save()

Comment: after `File.WriteAllBytes(SaveAsPath, mStream.ToArray()); ` does new file generated ?

Comment: I don't understand how should I use your example..because they are very different. And I'm new with this openxml..

Comment: the idea of my code is instead of access the excel file from it's path, access it through stream, so instead of passing destination to `SpreadsheetDocument.Open(destination, true))` get bytes from Memory stream and the pass `mStream ` to you code like `SpreadsheetDocument.Open(mStream, true))`

Comment: can you please edit it in order to work? or am I asking to much? :)

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot..is there anyway to choose the name of the sheet?

Comment: Then i think at least a vote up would be nice idea ;)

Comment: I suppose `sheetPart.Name` would change the name of sheet

Comment: I' ve voted..but I'm not allowed yet. I'm new here. srry :|